# WordPress Function - fix to stop repeating code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following PHP script to find the most recent post on the `Team` area of my site.

I also use a very similar one to find the most recent news entry on my home page.

To reduce the amount of repeated code (`DRY`), is there a way I can use a function and just pull in a specific custom post type e.g.  `most_recent('team');` would show the most recent post from my `Team` CPT.

Here's my existing code:

```
<?php
    // find most recent post
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        "post_status"=>"publish"
    ));
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function most_recent($type) {
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => $type,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        "post_status"=>"publish"
    ));


if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post();

          echo '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';

          the_content();

    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

Comment: With a bit of work, that worked perfectly. Now it seems super obvious : ) I changed line 3 to read `'post_type' => $type,`

Comment: Woops, sorry about that! Trying to answer two questions at once. Post has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is indeed possible.

First what you need to do is ,

Add below code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function most_recent($name){

    // find most recent post
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => $name,
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                        "post_status"=>"publish"
                ));

    if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post();

          echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>";
          the_content();

            endwhile;
    else:
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Now you can use it any where in your theme folder template like below:

```
 $most_recent = most_recent('product');
 echo $most_recent;
```

So in your case, it would be `most_recent('team')` or even you can use for other as well just like I did for `product`.

Tell me if you have any doubt.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer & detailed response. I found it very helpful :)

Comment: Glad that You found it helpful :) Happy Coding !